# md-input-container (Material Design) not working after update from Angular 2 to Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have updated a project from Angular 2 with Material Design to Angular 4 and now I'm having a very strange issue: in all browsers, except FireFox on a Mac, the placeholder and text are not visible in an input field.

This is how it looks in Chrome:
[App in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IafF9.png)

And this is how it looks in FireFox on a Mac:
[App in FireFox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krPp3.png)

And I don't get any errors when I run the app.

This is what my systemjs.config.js looks like:

```js
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    map: {
      Application: 'bin-debug',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/cdk': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk.umd.js',
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',
      '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
      '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',

      // CDK individual packages
      '@angular/cdk/platform': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-platform.umd.js',
      '@angular/cdk/a11y': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-a11y.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs'
    },
    packages: {
      Application: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        main:'./bundles/rx.min.js', defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

And this is my package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "testApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^4.3.2",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.42",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.17",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-shell": "^2.1.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.5.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rollup": "^0.45.2",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^8.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^3.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^2.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.17",
    "tslint": "^5.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.16"
  }
}
```

Does anybody has any idea what's happening? I've been looking at this problem for a long time now and I'm running out of ideas.

Here's more code about the implementation of the component:
Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Register CME - Pegasus Lectures</title>

  <base href="/">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://gitcdn.link/repo/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>

  <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.import('Application').catch(function (err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <nl-ixms-app>Loading...</nl-ixms-app>

</body>
</html>
```

ApplicationModule.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MdInputModule } from '@angular/material';
import { Application } from './components/Application';

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ Application ],
  declarations: [
    Application
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MdInputModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

Application.ts

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  moduleId: 'src/application/components/a',
  providers: [ ],
  selector: 'nl-ixms-app',
  styleUrls: [ './Application.css' ],
  templateUrl:  './Application.html'
})
export class Application {

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //
  //  Constructor
  //
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  constructor() {  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //
  //  LifyCycle Methods
  //
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  //-----------------------------------
  //  ngOnInit
  //-----------------------------------

  //noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Application ready');
  }

}
```

And a very minimal Application.html

```
<md-input-container>
<input placeholder="email address"
         mdInput
         required
         #email
         type="email"
         name="email">
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: Would you mind adding a snippet of how you've implemented the component in your view?

Comment: Since you moved from Angular 2 to 4, means you made a big jump in Material versions as well, last compatible Material with Angular2 was beta 2, current version is beta 8. Check if you are importing modules the [proper way](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started), and if you are using the current version of prebuilt theme css file.

Comment: Looks like you shouldn't mix `cdk-builds` master builds with a  release of `@angular/material` and that if you want to install from `master`, you should run `npm install angular/material2-builds`.

Comment: As suggested by @Edric, I have changed my package.json and systemjs.config.js to correctly use the release version of Material. But this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer: it was a css problem. The html still had this css file included:

```
   <link href="https://gitcdn.link/repo/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I can't remember why I used this css, but removing it solved the problem.